# Symfony 5 - Make:entity in custom folder?

Tags: symfony, directory, doctrine, entity

in my Symfony 5 application I have an architecture like this:

```
src/
├─ Website/
│  ├─ Entity/
│  ├─ Repository/
│  ├─ Controller/
├─ Application/
│  ├─ Entity/
│  ├─ Repository/
│  ├─ Controller/
```

When I create an entity with the command `php bin/console make:entity`, I would like to be able to specify on which folder to create the entity, and that it also creates the repository on the correct folder automatically.

Here is my configuration of the **doctrine.yaml** file

```yaml
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App\Application:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Application/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Application\Entity'
                alias: Application

            App\Website:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Website/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Website\Entity'
                alias: Website
```

For the moment, the only solution I have found is the following:

[image]

1. `php bin/console make:entity`
2. I wait for it to ask me for the path, and I enter this if I want to create the entity **Totoo** in the `src/Application/Entity` folder : `\App\Application\Entity\Totoo`
3. It does create the entity on `src/Application/Entity/Totoo.php`
4. But it will create the repository on `src/Repository/Application\Entity\TotooRepository.php`

How could we optimize this way of creating entities with the command, in order to automatically create the entity and the repository in the right place, and if possible without having to type the full path each time? (Maybe thanks to the aliases in my doctrine setup? But I don't see how)

Comment: I don't think this is a use case covered by the MakerBundle and likely is not something that will happen, because it can easily lead to bugs when people forget to adjust their config like you did. You might want to consider putting all your entities in a shared dir and use subfolders, so src/Entity/Application instead of src/Application/Entity. Alternatively create you entities manually or move them after creation.

Comment: Could be help this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594542/symfony-4-how-to-organize-folder-structure-namely-your-business-logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform this do you need to add a `maker.yaml` file
with the following lines (e.g)

```
# config/package/dev
maker:
  root_namespace: 'App\Application\'
```

When you will type : `bin/console make:entity` the new entity or modifying an existing Entity will check it out into this folder.

P:S watch out in which env do you configure it, dev in my case

That's it ;)